# convert string to a xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

How to save a well formed **xml** string to a **xml** file ?

Thanks in advance...

Hi All.... I got the answer

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("WellFormedXMLString");
            xmlDoc.Save(@"drive:\name.xml");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? XML is textual already. Can you give examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with simply writing your string to disk?

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\file.xml"))
{
    writer.Write("Xml data");
    writer.Flush();
}
```

or if you want to "test" it:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    doc.LoadXml(data);
}
catch
{
    // Fix it
}
doc.Save(@"C:\file.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write any string to disk like so:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\myfile.xml", yourXmlString);
```

If you have a string that is not a well-formed xml string and you want to convert that to some other format, you will have to give us some example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am no C# programmer, but I guess you need something like this:

[xmlwriter tutorial](http://dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter)

Answer (score 0):

Save the string straight onto the disk. No need to convert it into XML.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need xml if it's just a string ? You could save a text file with the variabele name, and the string inside as variable value.

for example

MyTextVar1.txt would contain "MyTestSTring"

then you could get the var by:

var mystring = GetFileAsString( "MyTextVar1.txt" );

Answer (score 0):

The xml document is a text file itself. you only need to change its extension.